# Position relative with overflow and scroll

Tags: html, css, scroll, css-position

I have a `div` with a fixed height, and `overflow: auto`. In that `div`, I have a button that shows a small popup when pressed. The popup is using `position: absolute`, and the entire containing `div` has `position: relative` so that the popups do not get clipped by the overflow. My issue is that when I scroll, the popups with absolute position get positioned to where the button is as if there was no scrolling not to where it currently is. How can I get around this?

This is a CodePen mimicking my issue: https://codepen.io/Hunky524/pen/jOKxYby
When you hover over a grey box, the blue box shows at the top, but if you scroll down, and then hover over a grey box, the blue box becomes mispositioned.

This is a screenshot of the issue in my application. You can see my mouse over the button that shows the popup. I would expect the popup to appear where my mouse is, but because I've scrolled down a bit, it gets offset.
[image]

Comment: You would need to position your `.item` elements relative, so that they become the reference point for the absolute positioning of the children. But that will interfere with the overflow ... https://css-tricks.com/popping-hidden-overflow/ has a solution that uses a little bit of JS to calculate the correct positions.

Comment: if you accept some javascript, check here https://github.com/pierfarrugia/drop_down_click, dropdown is position on click element

Comment: @pierfarrugia I'll with something like this for now, thanks! Seems really odd that this is how absolute positioning works in a scroll area. What even are the use cases where that it is how it should behave?

Comment: @pierfarrugia Something to note though with your solution is it doesn't seem to work when inside a div with a scrollbar.

Comment: @Mark Lisoway, by the way, this drop down click was done for a header menu not exactly in your context. I will check later what's happening in a div with a scrollbar

Comment: @mark could you put the html css to have what we are seeing on the image?

Comment: @pierfarrugia I've found a solution that works for me, and written it as an answer below. Hopefully what I wrote makes sense, but I can answer any questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just gimme the code... Here is a working CodePen example. Notice now when you scroll down, and hover over a grey box, the blue popup is correctly aligned: https://codepen.io/Hunky524/pen/LYrrVZE

Further explanation...

I was able to come up with a solution for my specific problem. **Note:** This is not a general solution, and will only work for setups similar to mine. The most important part is that there is only one parent in the DOM tree that has `position: relative`, otherwise the function I made won't calculate the correct offset.

This is my HTML structure for reference. Written in Angular, and I left only what matters:

```
<!--  Important that no elements from the root HTML element to here have relative position  -->
<div style="position: relative; overflow-y: auto;">
    <!--  Many elements between these two elements  -->
    <!--  Also important that no elements between these have relative position  -->
    <button class="popup-parent" (focus)="onPopupFocus($event)">
        <span>{{ offset }}</span>
        <div class="popup">
            <!-- Popup content here  -->
        </div>
    </button>
</div>
```

```
.popup {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
}

.popup-parent:focus-within > .popup {
    display: block;
}
```

Then this was the code ran when the button element was focused (clicked):

```js
public onPopupFocus(event: FocusEvent): void {
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();

    const target = event.currentTarget as HTMLElement;
    const targetOffsetTop = target.offsetTop;

    // This is the first parent with relative positioning
    // We assume there are no other relative parents
    const offsetParent = target.offsetParent as HTMLElement;
    const offsetParentScrollOffset = offsetParent?.scrollTop ?? 0;

    const offsetTop = offsetParent.offsetTop + (targetOffsetTop - offsetParentScrollOffset);

    // We assume the popup DIV card will always be after an initial SPAN
    const popup = target.children[1] as HTMLElement;

    popup.style.top = `${offsetTop}px`;
}
```

Now, in the picture you can see that even being scrolled almost all the way down, the popup is positioned correctly, while also **not** being clipped by the overflow, and being able to extend outside of the parent card.

[image]

A more general solution would require doing some kind of recursive calling on the parent offset elements until you reach the root HTML element, and summing up all the offsets.